# How to copy a formula hidden in a row at the bottom of a table to the active cell located in the same column using code assigned to a button?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in a worksheet that tracks who and when a person is assigned to perform a duty. The table has a header row with dates. The leftmost 2 columns have the title and name of the individuals (roster). Only one person per date is assigned to the specific duty. The bottom row of the table contains the formula that I want to copy to the active cell in the same column in the table when the button is clicked. I have made several attempts to accomplish this task, but all have been riddled with errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub PasteFormula() 
' 
' PasteFormula Macro 
' Pastes a formula from the table's bottom row, that is hidden, into the active cell of the same column. 
' 
'
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders 
ActiveSheet.Paste 
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub PasteFormula()
'
' PasteFormula Macro
' Pastes a formula from the table's bottom row, that is hidden, into the active cell of the same column.
'

'
    
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: I am new to posting into forums. Please excuse my clunky attempts to share.

Comment: gotcha. I edited the code into your question. Please make any changes to the code if the edit is not correct.

Comment: I have researched this thoroughly and can only find examples where the cell to be copied is a predefined cell in the worksheet.  For my solution to work correctly, the cell to be copied will change with respect to the column where the active cell is located.

Comment: Is the table formatted as an Excel table (using Ctrl+T)?

Comment: The table is formatted as an Excel table, yes.  I used the "insert table" command once the range was selected. I then chose the proper format from the predefined templates to define the table's format.

Comment: A table is a [`ListObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject). So you can use the inbuilt properties of a `ListObject`. What is your table named?

Comment: "fillRange" is the table name.  It is of the size C1:BC19.  The top row is the Header Row that contains the dates.

Comment: I would like to assign the code to be activated by a button on the same sheet.  The reason for this is to make updating the table more simple. I will not be the only one updating this sheet and other users often break the formula integrity of the sheet.

Comment: I can accomplish the button creation.  I just cannot get the code to work properly, if its even doable.

Comment: See my posted answer... change the `Table1` to `fillRange` and the `Sheet1` to your sheet name.

Comment: If you are familiar with the military-i.e. the Army, this is an attempt to automate a DA Form 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this, using the inbuilt properties of a `ListObject`. Change the sheet and table names as needed.

```
Sub PasteMyFormula()
    Dim myTbl As ListObject
    Set myTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

    With myTbl
        If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, .DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange(.ListRows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).Copy
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    End With        
End Sub
```